# Which CSS properties allow comma separated values?

Tags: css

As I remember from my development and studies, I **haven't faced CSS properties, that allow coma separated values** to be set. Or maybe I encountered them, but very rarely, therefore don't remember any.
I am not referring to *filter* property values, but they are also welcome to be noted.

**Could you please point out if you know ones (CSS2, 3 suits)? And if they exists at all?**

After getting your answers, I am going to check [W3C Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) to find out if they exist.

Example:

```
selector { property: value, value, value; }
```

Comment: `background-image` for one - you can set [multiple background-images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Multiple_backgrounds) at once.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, true, very good add.

Comment: @easwee That list is only for CSS 2 properties. CSS 3 modules add lots of new properties... I am not aware of any single property index table for all CSS 3 properties.

Comment: i wonder if someone has an actual list of all properties, sort of like MDN has a list of all animatable properties

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You really just need to reference [the property table](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html).

Any css function, such as `rgb()`, takes its parameters as CSV (i.e. `rgb(107, 203, 84)`)

In CSS2, the properties that might be separated via commas are:

- `cursor` – if you're using a custom `<uri>`
- `font` – see `font-family`
- `font-family` – separating each font-family value (i.e. `Arial, sans-serif`)
- `voice-family` – for listing `<specific-voice>` or `<generic-voice>` options.

Finding all the CSS3 properties that might allow CSV is a bit more challenging. CSS3 has been treated more as a set of modules to enhance CSS2 than a full blown spec to replace CSS2.

[CSS backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/) allows the following properties to support CSV:

- `background` – multiple background rules are separated, due to this all background sub-properties may also use CSV
- `background-color`
- `background-image`
- `background-repeat`
- `background-attachment`
- `background-position`
- `background-clip`
- `background-origin`
- `background-size`

[CSS Color Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/) adds `rgba()`, `hsl()`, and `hsla()` for color functions, all of which take comma-separated parameters

[CSS Text Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/)

- `text-shadow`

[CSS Transitions Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/)

- `transition` – similar to `background`, multiple transitions are separated by `,`, and all sub-properties also use CSV.
- `transition-delay`
- `transition-duration`
- `transition-property`
- `transition-timing-function`

[CSS Animations Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/)

- `animation` – see `transition`
- `animation-delay`
- `animation-direction`
- `animation-duration`
- `animation-iteration-count`
- `animation-name`
- `animation-play-state`
- `animation-timing-function`

`cubic-bezier()` function

[CSS Fonts Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/)

- `font-feature-settings`

`character-variant()`, `styleset()`,

Answer (score 6):

others

```
selector {
  font-family: "lucida grande" , tahoma, Arial;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,#f1f1f1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

CSS3 `text-shadow` and `box-shadow` properties:

```
p{

    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000, -2px -2px #fff;

}
```

Thus being separate 'values' of the same property, multiple text-shadows or box-shadows

Answer (score 2):

Multiple backgrounds:

```
background: url(sheep.png) center bottom no-repeat, url(betweengrassandsky.png) left top no-repeat;
```

There's a few related to background, there more like sub properties rather than directly a property.

Linear gradient:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(184,33,91) 49%, rgb(221,60,119) 75%);
```

Radial gradient:

```
background-image: radial-gradient(center center, circle contain, black 0%, blue 25%, green 40%, red 60%, purple 80%, white 100%);
```

Also the @font-face src property, however the @font-face isn't really a selector, so slightly off topic to your question. But still related.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: bodytext;
  src: url(ideal-sans-serif.woff) format("woff"),
       url(basic-sans-serif.ttf) format("opentype");
}
```